# How can I use Resultsets in the new JXLS version?

Tags: jxls

I created a lot of reports with JXLS in the old version (1.0.x). I basically run a query in my application and I pass the resultset as a collection to feed the report: http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/samples/resultsetsample.html

Simple! :-)

However, in the recent JXLS version, i cant't do the same...  It looks like it got a bit more complicated.

What is the simplest way to pass the resultset to fill out reports in the new version of JXLS? I've seen that you can put the query in the template, but I'd like to pass the Resultset instead.

Answer (score 0):

Copy [JdbcHelper](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/src/c9f5768612de14225b41ebafcbfdde8e27321f7f/src/main/java/org/jxls/jdbc/JdbcHelper.java?at=master) utility class from Jxls-2 library into your source code and change the modifier of the method

```
List<Map<String, Object>> handle(ResultSet rs)
```

to *public* so that you can use it to pass a result set and get back the collection.

Alternatively you can write your own method to convert the ResultSet into the collection or use the one which is used in Jxls-1.

Then just use the utility class to convert the ResultSet into the collection and apply it in your template.